# MERN-How to get data which is in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have an react-app .. I don't know the method to get data from the array from mongo db which has a structure [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XiVn.png)

I used `{this.props.obj.index}` to get index value and so on.. but i dont know how to gegt from array `{this.props.obj.songdata.object.songindex}` . help me

Comment: use `{this.props.obj.songdata[0].songindex}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `{this.props.obj.songdata[0].songindex}`

Comment: Mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

We use the map function in React to load data from the backend for example in your case

```
{obj.map((objct)=>{ <p>objct.title</p> })}
```

if there is an array inside your document then repeat the same process for that array-like

```
{obj.map((objct)=>{ objct.songdata.map((songInfo)=>{ <p>songInfo.songindex</p>}) })}
```

It is the same as looping through the array in js.